# Números menores que a média

Tags: java, array

Preciso fazer a média de 20 números e apresentar todos os números menores que a média.

```
package pag1;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ex2 {
public static void main (String[] args){
    Scanner x = new Scanner(System.in);

    int soma = 0;
    int posicao = 0;
    double [] numeros = new double [20];
    System.out.println("Digite 20 números para obter a média dos mesmos:");

    while (posicao < numeros.length){
        numeros [posicao] = x.nextDouble();
        posicao++;          
    }
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(numeros));
    for(int i=0; i<numeros.length; i++){
        soma += numeros[i];

    }
    int media = soma / numeros.length;
    System.out.println("soma: " + soma);
    System.out.println(media);

}

}
```

Faltou apenas a parte de mostrar os números menores que a média, mas não faço ideia de como.

Comment: Por quê não percorrer a lista, comparar cada valor com a média e, se for menor, exibir o número?

Comment: Sou iniciante, como poderia fazer isso?

Comment: Da mesma forma que você fez o resto do código. Qual é exatamente a dificuldade? Foi você mesmo que fez o código?

Comment: Sim, estou tentando, a dificuldade é que não sei qual comando usar para comparar cada item do array com a média final.

Comment: Utilizando o operador `<`: fazer `if (x < y)` retorna verdadeiro se o valor de `x` é menor que o de `y`.

Answer (score 1):

Primeiramente, acho que a sua variável media tem que ser do tipo double. Solução: Basta percorrer o vetor e verificar quais numeros são menores do que a media!

trecho:

```
for(int i=0; i<numeros.length; i++){
    if(numeros[i] < media)
        System.out.println(numeros[i]);

}
```

Comment: Agora, sendo `numeros[i]` do tipo `double` e `media` do tipo `int`, quais são os cuidados a serem tomados?

Comment: Na verdade, não faz muito sentido ele está usando uma variável inteira para média. Acho que o melhor a se fazer é colocar média para double. Mas do jeito que está o código, talvez seja preciso fazer um cast.

Comment: Então aproveite e edite a resposta adicionando isso. E se os dois forem do tipo `double`, quais serão os cuidados?

Comment: Não vejo nenhum problema, qual seria o problema ?

Comment: Alguns números não podem ser representados com exatidão. Embora seja difícil de acontecer, uma comparação entre dois valores com ponto flutuante pode gerar um resultado inesperado. Por exemplo, se dividir 26.55 por 3 dá 8.85, mas no Java, fazendo `26.55f/3` dá 8.849999. Se o usuário digitasse 3 valores e a soma resultasse em 26.55, e sendo um dos valores igual a 8.8499999, seria esperado que esse valor fosse exibido na saída, pois é menor que 8.85, que seria a média, mas não. Por causa desse detalhe, o valor 8.8499999 é maior que 26.55f/3 e não seria exibido.

Comment: ah, verdade. Já ouvi falar sobre isso mesmo. Obrigado por lembrar. Mas  acho que a dúvida dele é mais na questão da lógica de resolver. Acrescentar mais isso talvez confunda um pouco a solução. Além do mais, o problema é bem simples :)

Comment: Mas sobre a média estar como `int` é fundamental comentar. Acredito que você pode completar a resposta pelo menos com isso.

Answer (score 1):

Como complemento às respostas existentes, apresento uma utilizando *streams* e *lambdas*, que fará a impressão impressão dos valores abaixo da média de uma forma mais compacta.

Calculo da média:

```
double media = Arrays.stream(numeros).average().getAsDouble();
```

Impressão dos valores abaixo da média:

```
Arrays.stream(numeros).filter(num->num < media).forEach(num->System.out.println(num));
```

Em que o `filter` manteve só os elementos abaixo da média com `num->num < media`, e com o `forEach` mostra-se os que ficaram.

[Veja o código a funcionar no Ideone](https://ideone.com/wkTK0Z)

Answer (score 0):

Encontrei uma solução:

```
package pag1;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ex2 {
public static void main (String[] args){
    Scanner x = new Scanner(System.in);

    double [] menoresque = new double [20];
    int soma = 0;
    int posicao = 0;
    double [] numeros = new double [20];
    System.out.println("Digite 20 números para obter a média dos mesmos:");

    while (posicao < numeros.length){
        numeros [posicao] = x.nextDouble();
        posicao++;          
    }
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(numeros));
    for(int i=0; i<numeros.length; i++){
        soma += numeros[i];

    }
    int media = soma / numeros.length;
    System.out.println("soma: " + soma);
    System.out.println(media);
for(int i=0; i<numeros.length; i++){
    if (numeros[i] < media) {
    menoresque[i]=numeros[i];
    }

}for(int i=0; i<menoresque.length; i++){
    if(menoresque[i] != 0){
System.out.print(menoresque[i]+", ");
    }
}
}
}
```